# How to open tabs dynamically in my application

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

In one of my pages I want open tabs dynamically on clicking of likes like Rediffmail.com

For example:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: You could try searching "jQuery Tooltip" on google, it gives some nice results.

Comment: Are you talking about tabs or the tooltip thing?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really laughing in why are they giving you links about tooltips when what you wanted is to **open tabs dynamically**. LOL

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check out http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html